How to set up a new Spring Boot project using Java 8 despite default support for Java 17, 21, and 22?
I'm planning to start a new Spring Boot project and need to use Java 8 due to specific dependency requirements and compatibility with other systems. However, when using tools like Spring Initializr, the default Java versions offered are newer (17, 21, 22). I understand that these are the versions currently supported by the latest releases of Spring Boot, but my project constraints necessitate Java 8.
Could someone guide me on how to correctly set up a Spring Boot project in IntelliJ IDEA or any other IDE with Java 8? Additionally, if there are any known issues or important considerations when using Java 8 with newer Spring Boot versions, those insights would be extremely helpful!

Spring Boot 3 requires java 17 or up, it won't run on lower versions. Your only option is to use Spring Boot 2.7 and manually switch to java 8. However JDK 8 support ended in 2022 (from Oracle unless you have a paid subscription), Spring Boot 2.7 support ended november 2023 (unless you have a commercial support license). So do you really want to run with unsupported versions.

Using older versions of Spring also leaves you open for security vulnerabilities. You might want to discuss that with the folks that make the constraints.

Spring Boot 3.0 need Java min of 17 based on the release notes
